# rails login form slides down from header, when login attempt fails, how can i keep login form open?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

If the login attempt fails, redirect_to :back just reloads the previous page but does not continue showing the dropdrown form.

EDIT:

"[form_for guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) suggests using Ajax:

5.2 Dealing with Ajax
Unlike other forms, making an asynchronous file upload form is not as simple as providing form_for with remote: true."

This implies that remote: true is Rails built-in Ajax?

How do I properly add remote: true to my form?

Edit:

[This question might be helpful for those trying to solve these issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944425/rails-redirect-with-call-to-ajax)

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'         
      redirect_to :back 
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
    $('.sessions').hide();
    $('li.close-header').hide();
    $('li.signin').on('click', function() {
    $('li.signin').fadeOut(100);
    $('.sessions').slideDown(500);
    $('li.close-header').fadeIn(100);
    $('li.close-header').on('click', function() {
    $('.sessions').slideUp(500); 
    $('li.close-header').fadeOut(100);
    $('li.signin').fadeIn(100);
  }); 
  });  
});
```

Form

```
<div class="sessions">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= link_to "(forgot password)", new_password_reset_path %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "checkbox inline" do %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary sessions" %>
  <% end %>

   <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %> </p>         
</div>
```

Comment: render text or js from controller to tell your login handle to display error & don't do this `redirect_to root_url` or `redirect_to :back` in case of error.

Comment: do i need `remote: true` in my form? i have tried inserting it but not successfully.

Comment: yeah allow remote true

Comment: Can you show me with code?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944425/rails-redirect-with-call-to-ajax) topic for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add remote: true to the form to process it with ajax and create a create.js.erb file and render errors in the view. also consider adding client side validations to go along with server side validations.