# Rails: redirect with call to Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

I'm trying to redirect un-logged-in users directly to a login window, which is a bootstrap modal window.

I wrote a method called `logged_in_user` in `ApplicationController`:

```
def logged_in_user
  unless !current_user.nil?
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

The `login_url` routes to `sessions#new`, which I defined as below:

```
(sessions_controller.rb)

def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Here is the view that `redirect_to root_url` points to:

```
  <!-- Login Window -->
  <div id="login-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="login" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Here is `new.js.erb` that gets executed when `sessions#new` is called:

```
$("#login-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'sessions/new') %>");
```

Thus the login form, which is `_new.html.erb` in `app/views/sessions`, will appear as a popup window once the `sessions#new` is called.

Except that it has to be processed as JS rather than HTML. So I have the following link, which is in the `_header.html.erb` and available across all views, to ensure this is the case:

```
<%= link_to "Log in", login_path, {remote: true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#login-window'} %>
```

This works fine when the link is clicked. This is why I chose to do `redirect_to root_url` rather than `redirect_to login_url` in `logged_in_user` method as the latter approach results in "Missing Template error".

But what I really want is for users to be redirected straight to the popup window, rather than them being redirected to root_url first and having to click "Login" link to enter the form.
In other words, I need a way to somehow redirect users to the `sessions#new` by issuing an Ajax request so that `sessions#new` can be processed as JS.

I tried the following approaches for the desired redirect within `logged_in_user` method, none of which worked:

```
render js: "window.location = <%= escape_javascript(render 'sessions/new') %>"

render js: "window.location = '/sessions/new'"

redirect_to login_url, format: "js"
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#login-window') != -1) {
    $('#login-window').modal('show');
  }

});

</script>
```

And

```
redirect_to root_url+"#login-window"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was close! Though the desired visual effect (ie. fade) was achieved by your code, the form itself did not appear.

Comment: whats point load session/new by `$("#login-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'sessions/new') %>");`?
Use ajax when when data is dynamic. You 'sessions/new' is dynamic html? i think - no. 
Just load inside html.erb by render.
Form must appear if it`s modal bootstrap and no js errors.

Comment: Well, it's just for users "cliking" the link named "Log in". Anyway, the issue was solved inspired by your suggestion. I'll post the answer myself. Thank you very much for your insightful advice!

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by modifying the following files:

---

(*application_controller.rb*)

```
def logged_in_user
  unless !current_user.nil?
    session[:modal] = true
    redirect_to !request.referrer.nil? ? (request.referer + "#login-window") : "#login-window" 
  end 
end
```

I've omitted `flash[:danger]` because it was shown "behind" the faded 
screen. I've added `request.referer` to make sure that the login popup window appears where the user has made a request, rather than redirecting them to root_path. I thought this would be better for user experience. (The ternary was just to handle the case where `request.referer` can be `nil`, in which case the code rases an error.)
The motif behind `session[:modal] = true` is explained below.

---

(at the bottom of *application.html.erb*)

```
<% if session[:modal] == true %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if(window.location.href.indexOf('#login-window') != -1) {
        $('#login-window').modal('show');
        $("#login-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'sessions/new') %>");
      }
    });
  </script>
  <% session[:modal] = false %>
<% end %>
```

Here I'm using javascript directly inside the view template. Since the view template upon which the popup window appears is not limited to one particular template, I've out the script inside `application.html.erb`, which applies to all view templates. The first half of it was inspired by [cruncher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4464811/cruncher) 's answer. (Thank you cruncher!) I've then added `$("#login-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'sessions/new') %>");` to make sure that the login form (``app/views/sessions/_new.html.erb) does appear.

Now, since I want the login popup window to appear only when non-logged-in users try to access pages which require login, I went ahead and added `session[:modal] = true` to indicate that `logged_in_user` method was indeed called, which means that the above situation indeed occurred.

Then, inside `application.html.erb` I can check whether the popup window should appear by `<% if session[:modal] == true %>`. If that's the case, then the script will be executed, after which I set the value of `session[:modal]` to  `false`.

This `session[:modal]` logic may not be necessary (in fact, it worked fine without it), but I've added it just in case.

---

That's it :)

Also, for those of you who want to implement this pop-up window functionality with bootstrap, here is a blog I've found really useful:

https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals

Happy coding!

Comment: So the modal only shows when pages/links that require user to be logged in are opened?

Comment: In my application, it also opens when a user clicks a link "Log in" in the header.

Comment: What happens if Java script is not enabled on their browser

Comment: please update on your findings if you have the time, very helpful topic